# How do I get the browser to run javascript sent back following an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using jEditable to allow users to correct phone numbers and email addresses in a table, updating the database as they press enter.  The problem is the response back from the server is just being interpreted as text by the client, when in fact there is some javascript code I want executed.

The way jEditable works is that you unobtrusively attach the "editable" action to a DOM element, which is working great. Watching what the client is sending to the server using tcpdump I can see that the POST is html, with X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest; and what comes back from the server is Content-Type: text/javascript.

The Rails controller action in question is verify_email, and since I have all the verify logic working perfectly but the client side javascript isn't, I've shortened the controller action to simply:

```
def verify_email
  respond_to do|format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And similarly simplified verify_email.js.erb to be just

```
$(function(){ console.log("hello from verify_email callback")});
```

You'd think I'd get a pleasant greeting in the browser console, but no, instead the value of the td changes to be the text '$(function(){ console.log("hello from verify_email callback")});'

Attaching the jEditable functionality to the table data is done by class:

```
$(function() {
    $('.email')
        .editable('http://newserver.us.org:3001/directory/review/verify_email', {
            indicator : '<%= image_tag "wait18trans.gif", :title => "wait" %>',
            tooltip : "Click to edit...",
            }
        })
})
```

I just can't see where the error is.  I'm comparing against a control that does not use jEditable: I have a checkbox that posts on change:

```
$(function() {
    $('.checkmark').change(function() {
            $.post("http://newserver.us.org:3001/directory/review/checkmark",
            {"id" : $(this).attr("id")})
        });
});
```

and when I put the same console log message into checkmark.js.erb, I get pleasant greeting.  Over the wire the headers look the same.

My current thinking is that jEditable tweaks the DOM to insert a text input field, and then removes it, this is somehow interfering with the javascript response?!?

I added a callback to the jEditable to see what is coming back, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.email')
        .editable('http://newserver.us.org:3001/directory/review/verify_email', {
            indicator : '<%= image_tag "wait18trans.gif", :title => "wait" %>',
            tooltip : "Click to edit...",
            callback : function(value, settings) {
                console.log(this);
                console.log(value);
                console.log(settings);
            }
        })
})
```

And that produces console logging of:

```
[Log] <td class=​"email" id=​"2-3--1347-597" title=​"Click to edit...">​$(function(){ console.log("hello from verify_email callback")});
[Log] $(function(){ console.log("hello from verify_email callback")});​
[Log] Object
ajaxoptions: Object
autoheight: true
autowidth: true
callback: function (value, settings) {
event: "click.editable"
height: 35
id: "id"
indicator: "<img alt="Wait18trans" src="/directory/images/wait18trans.gif" title="wait" />"
loaddata: Object
loadtext: "Loading..."
loadtype: "GET"
name: "value"
onblur: "cancel"
placeholder: ""
submitdata: Object
target: "http://newserver.us.org:3001/directory/review/verify_email"
tooltip: "Click to edit..."
type: "text"
width: 202
__proto__: Object
```

It's just not helpful that `value` is a string of javascript.

Ultimately what I want the javascript to do is update the id of the td.  So maybe I need to grab a reference to the td before the jEditable post, to be used to find the correct element upon return?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that rails console log was giving me the information I needed to figure this out.

The checkbox, which didn't use jEditible, was being seen by rails this way:

```
Processing by ReviewController#checkbox as */*
```

My email tds were being seen by rails this way:

```
Processing by ReviewController#verify_email as HTML
```

Which is somewhat understandable then why everything I was sending back was simply being interpreted as HTML (even though I only had a responds_to |format| format.js...)

So in my assignment of jEditable to elements of class 'email' I added the ajaxoption of dataType : "" (JQuery docs say dataType is intelligent... jEditable was setting it to HTML)

```
$(function() {
    $('.email')
        .editable('http://newserver.us.org:3001/directory/review/verify_email', {
            indicator : '<%= image_tag "wait18trans.gif", :title => "wait" %>',
            tooltip : "Click to edit...",
            ajaxoptions : { dataType:""}
        })
})
```

And now everything is working like I intended!